# Install Canvas on a Raspberry pi

Tags: canvas, discord.js, npm-install

Hello I want to install canvas for a discord.js Bot.
When I try to install canvas with following command

`npm install canvas`

I get following error:

```
pi@server:~/Bots/Discord/Java $ npm install canvas

> canvas@2.6.1 install /home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for canvas@2.6.1 and node@12.18.4 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
Package pixman-1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.      
 Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pixman-1.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'pixman-1' found
    gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
    gyp ERR! configure error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.51-v7+
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
    gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas
    gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
    node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.4.51-v7+
    node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
    node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.4
    node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.11.0
    node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
    Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/pi/Bots/Discord/Java/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
    npm WARN java@1.0.0 No description
    npm WARN java@1.0.0 No repository field.
    
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! canvas@2.6.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@2.6.1 install script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/pi/.npm/_logs/2020-10-03T09_17_54_892Z-debug.log
```

Someone know why I get this error?
I use Node 12.18.4 on a Raspberry pi 3B

Thanks for answer
Tjum28 :)

Comment: Does this happen only for the `canvas` package?

Comment: I have also the discord.js installed via npm

Comment: Then, if you installed `discord.js` successfully, I'm thinking it might be because of the `canvas` package. As you can see in the error, it's trying to download [this](https://github.com/node-gfx/node-canvas-prebuilt/releases/download/v2.6.1/canvas-v2.6.1-node-v72-linux-glibc-arm.tar.gz), which returns a 404 (Not Found) error.

Comment: And have you an idea why it failed or have you an other way to install canvas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [node-canvas wiki](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/wiki/Installation%3A-Ubuntu-and-other-Debian-based-systems), You will need to install a few dependencies from apt.

Simply run:

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install build-essential libcairo2-dev libpango1.0-dev libjpeg-dev libgif-dev librsvg2-dev

After installing these canvas will install just fine.